# How can I selectively delete a Start Menu folder with NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I am using NSIS to create install and uninstall wizards to my rather simple app for Windows.

The situation is, my NSIS script creates a shortcut to the app in the Start Menu folder for the installation wizard. So far no problem. Other apps (related with mine) install their shourcts in the same Start Menu Folder too.

The problem is in the uninstall process. I can delete my shortcuts without a problem but, what about of the folder in the Start Menu? I cannot delete it if there are apps alredy there but I would like it to be removed if the folder is empty.

How can I check using the NSIS script if the folder is empty and therefore condition if the deletion of the folder has to happen or not?

Although is not vital I don't like to have empty useless folders cluttering my Start Menu view.

Thank you very much in advance!

Julen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RMDir "$SMPrograms\yourfolder"` will only delete the folder if it is empty